# What is the recommended approach to creating images for a dynamically sized ImageButton?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I need to create some images to fill a few ImageButton elements I've defined in XML, and the buttons resize automatically according to screen size.

For example, let's say I use Photoshop to create one of these images. How do I know what size to set the image, the resolution, the aspect ratio, etc? Obviously it isn't a good idea to stretch the images or anything like that, so I'm a bit lost.

I don't know if it's relevant in this case, but I'll leave my code here, along with a screenshot of what it looks like.

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="pt.ismai.a26800.readr.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</GridLayout>
```

**Layout**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/bumptech/glide You can set the DiskCacheStrategy to whatever behavior you'd like. This means that it can load the image to the size of the imageview or the full size image into memory.